# Wordpress performance is slow when user is logged in

Tags: wordpress

I have a website running on wordpress and i have installed W3 total cache plugin on it 
the problem i am facing is the site home page load in around 10 to 12 seconds when user is logged in.
The home page performance is fine when user is not logged in.
is there any other plugin i have to use or do i have to make modifications in the W3 total cache plugin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have any luck here, try [wordpress.se] stack exchange

Comment: Echoing aghoshx: If you are using caching to speed up your website, note that some (most?) services by default don't cache pages for logged-in users since these are custom and must be kept separately for each user (increasing cache size).  You need to manually enable it. As an example using the SiteGround web hosting provider, [here is a brief explanation for the SiteGround Optimizer Wordpress plugin](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/sg-optimizer/supercacher/).

Answer (score 2):

By default, W3 total cache plugin does not cache pages for logged in users, you can change this behavior by going to ***Performance ->  Page Cache*** page in your dashboard and unchecking the "***Don't cache pages for logged in users***" under the general tab. Hope that helps.

Comment: thnx for the reply but the problem is when i cache the pages for logged in users sometimes the anonymous user see  cached page of logged in user is there any solution for this i read the faqs of w3 total cache and i like the idea of fragment caching can i implement the frament caching if i am using memacache as cache storage ?

Comment: Not a very good idea, I can't suggest a better solution without knowing the site structure and functionality.

Comment: I have also tried WP Rocket's option for caching for logged in users but strangely enough, when I open the website in incognito mode it loads very fast but for a logged in user, it takes nearly 20 seconds for the page to load completely. I guess this might be addressed in the new version of WP.